# Python, GEOS and Shapely on Windows 64

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, shapely

When trying to install Shapely on my Windows 64bit computer, I cannot get the GEOS library to work.

So far, I have run the OSGeo4W installer from which I installed GDAL (I believe the geos library is included in that package). After that, I checked and I have geos_c.dll on my `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` directory, but either I have missed some configuration steps or the library does not work.

I need Shapely to work, so I also ran `pip install shapely` after  installing GDAL, and it apparently worked (although it could not find the C library for GEOS).

In my code, I can import Shapely, but when I try to use it, I get an error telling me `"geos.dll"` is not found.

Any help with this will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: Maybe you could use an installer at the bottom of [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2b6) page. That should include geos.

Comment: Cool!  Add this as an answer so I can accept it, please.

Comment: In my case, I had to switch to a lower (3.10 to 3.9) Python version

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Anaconda/Miniconda/Miniforge users should install Shapely (and dependencies) with:

```
conda install shapely
```

As of 2020, other Python users can install binary wheels from PyPI with pip:

```
pip install shapely
```

(you may need `--upgrade` to get at least version 1.7.0, when binary wheels were added.) Note that binary wheels are not available for Python 2 on Windows.

---

Another resource is Christoph Gohlke's [Geospatial library wheels for Python on Windows](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/) releases on GitHub. Download the latest Shapely wheels [from here](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/releases/latest), e.g., [`shapely-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/releases/download/v2023.4.22/shapely-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl) for 64-bit Python 3.9.

Comment: Make sure you install the version that matches your Python installation, NOT your OS. I made the mistake of installing the 64 bit shapely since I'm running 64 bit Windows, but my Python is 32 bit, and it gave me a similar "geos_c.dll" is not found.

Answer (score 6):

see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50623996/1683626

on windows 10, python 3.6.5 64bit

- install [osgeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)
- add installed folder to path e.g. C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
  (must contain geos_c.dll)
- restart command line

Answer (score 4):

There is an version of Shapely available [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2b6) that includes geos in the installer. Look at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This version is from 2010-04-13, and was compiled for 32-bit Python 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: you can find newer versions by modifying the version number in the url. E.g. [version 1.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.3.0) is from 2014 and works with python 2.7 and 3.3

Answer (score 2):

I tried the method of @jozef but failed even I imported the folder to the path.

A straightforward solution: add geos_c.dll, geos.dll to the library folder of your python environment. Then it works.

Comment: fastest fix, not sure that is se cleanest tho

Comment: You can download the dll at https://www.dll-files.com/geos_c.dll.html

Answer (score 1):

I used the command below and it did work;

pip install Shapely==1.3.0

Answer (score 1):

I've made it installing wheels for GDAL (and Fiona, in my case; might not be required) from   [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)
Providing a path to the geos_c.dll didn't work. Neither putting them into venv/Lib.