# import shapely.geometry throws AttributeError: function 'GEOSversion' not found

Tags: python, attributeerror, geos, shapely

`import shapely.geometry` works fine in the interpreter but the code throws this error when running:

```
AttributeError: function 'GEOSversion' not found
```

Also tried

```
import geos  
ImportError: No module named geos`
```

But Shapely used to run perfectly.

Have not found any post regarding this problem in SO. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Shapely‑1.3.2.win‑amd64‑py2.7.exe installed from [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) which is [supposed to include GEOS dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17849389/3012255).

Python 2.7 64bit Anaconda on Win7 64bit. Using Eclipse with PyDev

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\file.py", line 3, in <module>
import shapely.geometry
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 9, in <module>
from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shapely\coords.py", line 8, in <module>
from shapely.geos import lgeos
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 125, in <module>
geos_version_string, geos_version, geos_capi_version = _geos_version()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-          packages\shapely\geos.py", line 112, in _geos_version
GEOSversion = _lgeos.GEOSversion
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'GEOSversion' not found
```

Comment: With the first import, what is the traceback? The second import error is expected, since there is no `geos` module to import.

Comment: @MikeT the traceback is added to the post. Please take a look. Thank you