# Why I'm getting this error? What can be done to install osmnx on windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, shapely, osmnx

I'm not able to install osmnx in jupyter notebook. The following problem is occurring with shapely version 1.6

I could install shapely 1.4 but osmnx needs 1.6 version

The command I used is !pip install osmnx

Collecting Shapely>=1.6 (from osmnx)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/fb/7a7af9ef7a35d16fa23b127abee272cfc483ca89029b73e92e93cdf36e6b/Shapely-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\shrinath\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Shrinath\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_oopeoz\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Shrinath\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3_oopeoz\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\Shrinath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_oopeoz\Shapely\
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Shrinath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_oopeoz\Shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
    from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
  File "C:\Users\Shrinath\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3_oopeoz\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
    lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
  File "c:\users\shrinath\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, GEOS and Shapely on Windows 64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144158/python-geos-and-shapely-on-windows-64)

Comment: Tried to install through cmd in scripts of python3.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the installation instructions in the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/)? It recommends using pip only if you already have all the OSMnx dependencies already installed on your system (because some of them are tricky). From the link above: "If you have any trouble with the installation, try installing OSMnx in a new, clean conda environment using conda-forge and strict channel priority." This should fix it for you.