# Calculating the overlap area of two sloped rectangles using Python

Tags: python, math, geometry

I am having trouble to calculate the overlap area of two rectangles using Python.

**The rectangle may be sloped.**

The input is eight values: (left_top, right_top, left_bottom, right_bottom)

and the function should return the overlapping area.

[image: Example]

Is there a possible solution? Thanks you so much if you can help! :)

Comment: There might be a possible solution, but first we need to see yours. What's your proposal, what code have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: I have tried using PIL to draw transparent rectangles and calculate the darker color and it works, but it will cause performance issue. I have no idea how to implement it using pure calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate resulting intersection using algorithm from O'Rourke book "Computational Geometry in C" - [C code is availabl](http://www.science.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/books/ftp.html)e, file `convconv`.
[Algorithm outline is here](http://www.cs.uml.edu/%7Ekdaniels/courses/ALG_504_F12/ORourkeCH7.pdf)

Also you can use libraries like [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) - arbitrary found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57885406/get-the-coordinates-of-two-polygons-intersection-area-in-python?rq=1),  or [Clipper](http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) (has third party Pytgon modules)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by MBo in his answer, this can be easily achieved using **Shapely** and Python:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def get_overlap_polygon(rect1_coords, rect2_coords):
    rect1 = Polygon(rect1_coords)
    rect2 = Polygon(rect2_coords)
    poly_intersection = rect1.intersection(rect2)
    return poly_intersection.exterior.coords, poly_intersection.area
```

**Sample inputs:**
rect1_coords = [(1.1408563820557887, 0.20116376126988017), (0.7988362387301199, 1.1408563820557887),
(-0.14085638205578857, 0.7988362387301199), (0.20116376126988014, -0.14085638205578854),
(1.1408563820557887, 0.20116376126988017)]
rect2_coords = [(1.2044160264027588, 0.4383715832837807), (0.5616284167162194, 1.2044160264027588),
(-0.20441602640275877, 0.5616284167162194), (0.43837158328378056, -0.20441602640275866),
(1.2044160264027588, 0.4383715832837807)]

Output:

[image]