# Python 3.4 crashes when producing some – but not all – Cartopy maps with segmentation fault 11

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy, fink

I have installed the Python mapping tool Cartopy on a Mac running El Capitan 10.11.6 with Python 3.4. I can use Cartopy to successfully plot some maps but, in some cases, the Python kernel dies with Segmentation Fault 11.

I wanted a setup that I could remove easily from my computer should the need arise. Therefore, I installed Python 3.4 and the necessary dependencies using fink:

```
$ fink install python34
$ fink install gdal2
$ fink install gdal2-dev
$ fink install proj
$ fink install libproj9
```

I then created a virtual environment using pyvenv (but also tried virtualenv and venv) and activated it.

In the activated virtual environment, I used pip to install:

```
$ pip install cython        # Successfully installed cython-0.25.2
$ pip install numpy         # Successfully installed numpy-1.12.1
$ pip install shapely       # Successfully installed shapely-1.5.17.post1
$ pip install pyshp         # Successfully installed pyshp-1.2.10
$ pip install pandas        # Successfully installed pandas-0.19.2 python-dateutil-2.6.0 pytz-2017.2 six-1.10.0
$ pip install matplotlib    # Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 matplotlib-2.0.0 pyparsing-2.2.0
$ pip install pillow        # Successfully installed olefile-0.44 pillow-4.1.0
$ pip install pyepsg        # Successfully installed pyepsg-0.3.1
$ pip install scipy         # Successfully installed scipy-0.19.0
$ pip install OWSLib        # Successfully installed OWSLib-0.14.0 pyproj-1.9.5.1 requests-2.13.0
$ pip install mock          # Successfully installed mock-2.0.0 pbr-3.0.0
$ pip install nose          # Successfully installed nose-1.3.7
$ pip install pep8          # Successfully installed pep8-1.7.0
$ pip install jupyter       # Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.0 appnope-0.1.0 backports-abc-0.5 bleach-2.0.0 decorator-4.0.11 entrypoints-0.2.2 html5lib-0.999999999 ipykernel-4.6.1 ipython-6.0.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 ipywidgets-6.0.0 jedi-0.10.2 jinja2-2.9.6 jsonschema-2.6.0 jupyter-1.0.0 jupyter-client-5.0.1 jupyter-console-5.1.0 jupyter-core-4.3.0 mistune-0.7.4 nbconvert-5.1.1 nbformat-4.3.0 notebook-5.0.0 pandocfilters-1.4.1 pexpect-4.2.1 pickleshare-0.7.4 prompt-toolkit-1.0.14 ptyprocess-0.5.1 pygments-2.2.0 pyzmq-16.0.2 qtconsole-4.3.0 simplegeneric-0.8.1 terminado-0.6 testpath-0.3 tornado-4.5.1 traitlets-4.3.2 typing-3.6.1 wcwidth-0.1.7 webencodings-0.5.1 widgetsnbextension-2.0.0
```

The above seemed to meet all the Cartopy dependancy requirements listed at: http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/installing.html

I then installed Cartopy, ensuring to build against (if that's the correct term) the geos library installed with fink:

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/sw/opt/libgeos3.5.0/include" --global-option="-L/sw/opt/libgeos3.5.0/lib"  cartopy
                             # Successfully installed cartopy-0.14.2
```

I could run Python either in a Jupyter notebook or in the Terminal and it allowed me to import Cartopy with no errors. I downloaded some example code from the Cartopy website to test the installation.

The following example worked perfectly:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
ax.stock_img()
plt.show()
```

As did this code:

```
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 12))

# get the path of the file. It can be found in the repo data directory.
fname = os.path.join(config["repo_data_dir"],
                     'raster', 'sample', 'Miriam.A2012270.2050.2km.jpg'
                     )
img_extent = (-120.67660000000001, -106.32104523100001, 13.2301484511245, 30.766899999999502)
img = plt.imread(fname)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.title('Hurricane Miriam from the Aqua/MODIS satellite\n'
          '2012 09/26/2012 20:50 UTC')

# set a margin around the data
ax.set_xmargin(0.05)
ax.set_ymargin(0.10)

# add the image. Because this image was a tif, the "origin" of the image is in the
# upper left corner
ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m', color='black', linewidth=1)

# mark a known place to help us geo-locate ourselves
ax.plot(-117.1625, 32.715, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(-117, 33, 'San Diego', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

plt.show()
```

But this code caused the kernel to crash:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy

ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)

ax.set_extent([-20, 60, -40, 40])

plt.show()
```

When the code was entered line-by-line in the Terminal, all the lines were fine until either of the last two were entered.

The only error message produced at the command line was:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Has anyone comes across a reason and a solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error message you are seeing to the end of your post. This may help others identify the problem.

Comment: The only message was "Segmentation fault: 11". Have added to question.

Answer (score 4):

Finally managed to make some progress so I'll summarise my solution. It may not resolve all issues but it did fix the problem I was having initially.

I posted an issue on the Cartopy GitHub page (https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/879) where QuLogic suggested a solution to stop the segmentation fault by reinstalling shapely using:

```sh
    pip uninstall shapely; pip install --no-binary :all: shapely
```

This indeed stopped the segmentation fault 11 but running the 'problem' code then produced an error suggesting that the geos_c couldn't be found, even though it was present. The exact error was:

> OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS', '/opt/local/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'].

It seems that the code insisted in looked for this library in a predefined location and refused to look at the locations where fink had installed the library even though I had added to location to my .bash_profile file. The solution was to create a symbolic link in that predefined location that pointed to the fink installed library. Hope that makes sense. (See Jace Browning at [OSError geos_c could not be found when Installing Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578471/oserror-geos-c-could-not-be-found-when-installing-shapely/33093518#comment74679577_33093518)).

So here's a summary of my entire solution, in case it helps someone else. Any suggestions for improvements would be welcomed.

1. For the record, my setup is a standard (not admin) account on Mac OS 10.11.6 (El Capitan) running on an iMac. I do, however, also have access to an admin account if necessary.
2. Installed version Python 3.6 using the installer provided at python.org
3. As admin, used fink to install gdal2, gdal2-dev, libproj9, libgeos3.6.1. (Also used fink to install a version of python3.6, gdal-py36, freetype, freetype219, cairo, gsl, sqlite3 and libspatialite7 but not sure if these packages are absolutely necessary.)
4. Python 3.6 was installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6. Created a virtual enviroment (called venv36) using `-m venv` as follows:

At command-line:

```sh
    $ mkdir <name_of_directory_for_virtual_env>
    $ cd <name_of_directory_for_virtual_env>
    $ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -m venv venv36
```

5. In user account, used nano to edit the .bash_profile file to include paths to locations where fink installed libgeos3.6.1:

At command-line:

```sh
    $ cd
    $ nano .bash_profile
```

Added the following lines to the .bash_profile file and saved (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>):

```sh
    GEOS_CONFIG="/sw/opt/libgeos3.6.1/bin/geos-config"; export GEOS_CONFIG
    GEOS_DIR="/sw/opt/libgeos3.6.1"; export GEOS_DIR
```

6. Activated the virtual environment and pip installed required packages. The pandas and jupyter packages are optional but why wouldn't you want to install them?

At the command-line:

```sh
    $ cd <path_to_virtual_environment>
    $ source venv36/bin/activate
    
    (venv36) $ pip install cython
    (venv36) $ pip install numpy
    (venv36) $ pip install --no-binary :all: shapely
    (venv36) $ pip install pyshp
    (venv36) $ pip install pyproj
    (venv36) $ pip install six
    (venv36) $ pip install matplotlib
    
    (venv36) $ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/sw/include/gdal2/
    (venv36) $ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/sw/include/gdal2/
    (venv36) $ pip install gdal
    (venv36) $ pip install pillow
    (venv36) $ pip install pyepsg
    (venv36) $ pip install scipy
    (venv36) $ pip install OWSLib
    (venv36) $ pip install mock nose pep8
    (venv36) $ pip install pandas
    (venv36) $ pip install jupyter
    
    (venv36) $ pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/sw/opt/libgeos3.6.1/include" --global-option="-L/sw/opt/libgeos3.6.1/lib"  cartopy
```

7. Finally, added a symbolic link in /opt/local/lib/ (which is where cartopy – or some other package – insists on looking for libgeos) that points to the libgeos library installed by fink (called libgeos_c.1.dylib). It may be necessary to create the /opt/local/lib pathway (or bits of it) if it doesn't already exist.

Then, at the command-line:

```sh
    $ cd /opt/local/lib
    $ sudo ln -s /sw/opt/libgeos3.6.1/lib/libgeos_c.1.dylib libgeos_c.dylib
```

That's it. In the activated virtual environment, open jupyter-notebook. Make sure the first line contains the following if you want the maps to be drawn in the notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Then add the following to the next cell:

```
import cartopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)

ax.set_extent([-20, 60, -40, 40])

plt.show()
```

When the code is run, it will likely produce a warning (`Failed CDLL(/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/Current/GEOS)`) but it should, hopefully, still produce the following image:

[image: Map produced by cartopy code]

So, that's it. Hope it helps. Any comments or suggestions for improvements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I will write down my experience with this issue here, hoping it helps somebody.

**How I managed to install `Cartopy` on MacOS:**

I have MacOS 10.12.6, using a `virtualenv` with Python 3.7.0 (so I am **not** using `conda`).

1. Following the [requirements](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/master/INSTALL), install required Python libraries if you don't have them yet:

   ```
   pip install numpy  
   pip install Cython  
   pip install --no-binary :all: shapely  
   pip install pyshp  
   pip install six
   ```

   Obtaining the following versions in my case:

   ```
   numpy==1.15.3
   Cython==0.29
   Shapely==1.6.4.post2
   pyshp==2.0.1
   six==1.11.0
   ```
2. Also, I `brew` installed:

   ```
   brew install proj  
   brew install geos
   ```

   Getting versions:

   ```
   proj --> Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018
   geos-config --version --> 3.7.0
   ```

   Also add `export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.7.0/` to my `~/.bash_profile`.
3. Finally, `pip` install `Cartopy`:

   ```
   pip install Cartopy
   Cartopy==0.17.0
   ```

So *in principle*, `brew` installing `geos` should be enough (I read in several places about the [Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/) website, which should also be fine). Apparently, **the stopper for me** was

```
pip install --no-binary :all: shapely
```

**What is the explanation for this?**

Checking `Shapely`'s [installation instructions](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project.html#source-distributions):

> If you want to build Shapely from source for compatibility with other modules that depend on GEOS (such as **cartopy** or osgeo.ogr) or want
>   to use a different version of GEOS than the one included in the
>   project wheels you should first install the GEOS library, Cython, and
>   Numpy on your system (using apt, yum, brew, or other means) and then
>   direct pip to ignore the binary wheels.

**Conclusion**: I believe this should be included somewhere in `Cartopy`'s installation instructions for Mac users.

---

As [user1718097](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1718097/user1718097) mentions above, there is an [issue](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/879) in `Cartopy`'s GitHub repo with this information.