# Could not find module (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, geometry, multilinestring

When I run the command:

`from shapely.geometry import LineString`

I get this error:

`Could not find module 'C:\Users\SWWB\Anaconda\Library\bin\geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError geos\_c could not be found when Installing Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578471/oserror-geos-c-could-not-be-found-when-installing-shapely)

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: And what about the answers here [Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19742406/7851470)?

Answer (score 11):

I run into this same problem. I am using Pycharm on Windows 10 with a conda environment. I used pip to install the packages in my requirements.txt file.

I am using Shapely which depends on geos. It seems pip did not install that dependency, so what I did was to first remove Shapely with:

```
pip uninstall shapely
```

Then, I used conda to install the package (geos gets installed too), and everything works fine.

```
conda install shapely
```

I think if you use pip, you can just install geos individually if it is not installed (I did not test):

```
pip install geos
```

Comment: unfortunately ´´´pip install geos´´´ doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I reinstalled shapely using conda.

Use the following

```
conda install shapely
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tryed to reinstall shapely. But it didn't work. Maybe you could try to install pygeos using following command. It works to me.

```
pip install pygeos
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out your whether you are using Windows 32-bit or 64-bit. Go to Settings => System => About => System Type.
2. Find out your python version. Open Command prompt, enter python --version and remember the first two numbers. For example my version is Python 3.7.3 so I should remember the number 37.
3. pip install wheel
4. Go [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and download the wheel corresponding to items 1–2. For example, I have 64-bit OS and Python 3.7.3 so I need to download file Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
5. pip install <filename_from_item_4> .
   For example in my case I entered
   pip install C:\Users\Dalya\Downloads\Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
6. restart the python kernel

copied from here: https://towardsdatascience.com/install-shapely-on-windows-72b6581bb46c

Answer (score 0):

after following @MrZH6 advice, I noticed that I have python3.9, which comaptable only for shapely>=1.8, once I specified that version the installation using `pip install shapely>=1.8` worked perfectly