# Could not find module '...'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax

Tags: python, import, libraries

When I try to run:

```
from pyplutchik import plutchik
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find module 'C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Library\bin\geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578471/oserror-geos-c-could-not-be-found-when-installing-shapely

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.