# Couldn't able to find & install geos_c for shapely on mac?

Tags: python-3.x, geos

I am trying to run an api which has following pyproject.toml :

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.10.5"
Flask = "2.0.1"
gunicorn = "^20.1.0"
pymongo = "^3.12.2"
marshmallow = "^3.14.1"
dnspython = "^2.1"
requests = "^2.26.0"
sentry-sdk = {version = "^1.5.0", extras = ["flask"]}
shapely = "^1.8.0"
numpy = "^1.21.4"
jiwer = "2.2.0"
types-requests = "^2.26.1"
```

When I run this it throws following error :

```
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'].
```

Attached a screenshot [image: here]

What I tried till: using `pip install geos` which give version 0.2.3 which is certainly not my lookout result.
Also these few links :
[OSError geos_c couldn't found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578471/oserror-geos-c-could-not-be-found-when-installing-shapely)
or this :
[another SO question about geos_c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742406/could-not-find-library-geos-c-or-load-any-of-its-variants)
So, wanted to ask is there any other way to install **goes_c** on mac m1?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options mentioned in [this](https://github.com/shapely/shapely/issues/1080) thread.

For me installing the latest version of shapely (1.8.4) solved the problem with my M1.